# Como que eu posso fazer uma expressão "ternaria" de maneira mais simples

Tags: c#, razor

Não sei uma boa maneira de como se perguntar isso, dei uma pesquisada no google mas não achei oque eu queria, eu conheço a expressão `variavel?.atributo` que faz com que o código só tente pegar o atributo se a variavel tiver valor, se não retorna `null`

Também conheço a expressão `variavel ?? 0` que faz com que o código retorne 0 valor depois das `??` se o valor for `null`

A questão é, já ví códigos em que esses 2 são utilizados juntos, porém no meu código acabo recebendo um `null exception`.

Um exemplo do meu código atual:

```
var notaComp = notasFiltradas?.Where(x => x.TipoAvaliacao == (int)TipoAvaliacaoParcial.AutoAvaliacao)?.SingleOrDefault().Nota ?? 0;
```

Comment: Veja na descrição da null exeption qual é o campo que é nulo.

Comment: a enumeração não gerou resultados, é essa parte aqui que vem antes var notasFiltradas = Model.Notas.Where(x => x.IdCompetencia == competencia.IdCompetencia)

Comment: EM nenhum momento tem nada ternário neste código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de mais pesquisas no google encontrei uma sugestão que funcionou, apenas trocar o `SingleOrDefault` por `FirstOrDefault`, assim sendo caindo na expressão ternária ??

```
var notaComp = notasFiltradas?.Where(x => x.TipoAvaliacao == (int)TipoAvaliacaoParcial.AutoAvaliacao)?.FirstOrDefault().Nota ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode reduzir a condição do seu "Where" para dentro do FirstOrDefault desta forma:

```
var notaComp = notasFiltradas?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TipoAvaliacao == (int)TipoAvaliacaoParcial.AutoAvaliacao)?.Nota ?? 0;
```

Irá funcionar do mesmo jeito, mas você economizará um pouco de código, se caso o FirstOrDefault() não retornar nenhum valor, o `?` não irá permitir o acesso à propriedade Nota, e retornará 0;